# How can I set a svg path starting point?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, svg

I'm developing the loading animation below but I'm running into problems.
I can't get the heart's `stroke-dashoffset` animation to start at the crack, top center of the heart. To clarify, the red "border" animation is the problem. It's starting at the wrong place.

I am creating the heart shape in Illustrator.

- I make the shape https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEVWj.jpg
- Next I convert the svg primitives `<circle>` and `<rectangle>` to `<path>` so they can be animated. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rq6c5.jpg
- I union the circles and rectangle to make the heart shape. https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZpeb.jpg

**How can I get the red "border" animation to start at the crack of the heart?**

```css
body { margin: 0 }
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
h1 {
  font-family: 'Cabin Sketch', cursive;
  font-size: 4vw;
}
svg {
  width: 25vw;
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
}

.circleLeft {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #585858;
  stroke-width: 0.5;
  stroke-dasharray: 312;
  stroke-dashoffset: 312;
  transform-origin: 59% 97%;
  animation: leftCircleAnim 6s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, -0.03, 0.82, 0.42);
}

.circleRight {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #585858;
  stroke-width: 0.5;
  stroke-dasharray: 312;
  stroke-dashoffset: 312;
  transform-origin: 14% 54%;
  transition: 1s ease all;
  animation: rightCircleAnim 6s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, -0.03, 0.82, 0.42);
}

.rect {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #585858;
  stroke-width: 0.5;
  transition: 1s ease all;
  transform-origin: 64% 57%;
  stroke-dasharray: 303;
  stroke-dashoffset: 303;
  animation: rectAnim 6s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, -0.03, 0.82, 0.42);
}

.heart {
  stroke-dasharray: 332;
  stroke-dashoffset: 332;
  transition: 1s ease-in all;
  stroke: #E21A39;
  stroke-width: 0.5;
  fill: transparent;
  animation: heartAnim 6s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, -0.03, 0.82, 0.42);
}

@keyframes rectAnim {
  0% { stroke-dashoffset: 312; }
  10% { stroke-dashoffset: 122; }
  35% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  37% { stroke: #585858; }
  45% { transform: rotate(-45deg); stroke: #e8e8e8; }
  74% { opacity: 1 }
  75% { opacity: 0 }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 122;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    stroke: #e8e8e8;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}


@keyframes leftCircleAnim {
  10% { stroke-dashoffset: 312; }
  25% { stroke-dashoffset: 122; transform: translateY(0); }
  35% { transform: translateY(-22px); }
  37% { stroke: #585858; }
  45% { transform: translateY(-22px) rotate(-45deg); stroke: #e8e8e8; }
  74% { opacity: 1 }
  75% { opacity: 0 }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 122;
    transform: translateY(-22px) rotate(-45deg);
    stroke: #e8e8e8;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes rightCircleAnim {
  10% { stroke-dashoffset: 312; }
  25% { stroke-dashoffset: 122; transform: translateX(0); }
  35% { transform: translateX(22px); }
  37% { stroke: #585858; }
  45% { transform: translateX(22px) rotate(-45deg); stroke: #e8e8e8; }
  74% { opacity: 1 }
  75% { opacity: 0 }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 122;
    stroke: #e8e8e8;
    transform: translateX(22px) rotate(-45deg);
    opacity: 0
  }
}

@keyframes heartAnim {
  45% { stroke-dashoffset: 332; }
  55% { stroke-dashoffset: 102; }
  58% { fill: transparent; }
  65% { fill: #E21A39; }
  85% { opacity: 1; }
  95% { opacity: 0; }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 102;
    fill: #E21A39;
    opacity: 0; 
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin+Sketch" rel="stylesheet">

<main>
  <h1>Heart Creation Loading Animation</h1>
<svg viewBox="-0.5 -0.5 77.95 71.6">
  <title>heart</title>
  <path class="rect" d="M61.05,56H15.94V10.87H61.05V56Z"/>
  <path class="circleLeft" d="M15.94,33.43A22.55,22.55,0,0,0,55.85,47.84,22.56,22.56,0,0,0,34.12,11.29,22.53,22.53,0,0,0,15.94,33.43Z"/>
  <path class="circleRight" d="M15.94,33.43A22.55,22.55,0,0,0,55.85,47.84,22.56,22.56,0,0,0,34.12,11.29,22.53,22.53,0,0,0,15.94,33.43Z"/>
  <path class="heart" d="M180.09,6.55a22.89,22.89,0,0,0-25.74-4.38,22,22,0,0,0-6.11,4.4l0,0,0,0A22.54,22.54,0,0,0,110.52,25a22.64,22.64,0,0,0,5.85,13.35l0,0,31.9,31.9,31.9-31.9,0,0a21.77,21.77,0,0,0,1.65-1.8A22.83,22.83,0,0,0,180.09,6.55Z" transform="translate(-109.95 0.5)"/>
</svg>
</main>
```

I have a dev version where it's easier to mess with the heart's `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` here http://codepen.io/tryggvigy/pen/rWjZOE

Comment: If you use a vector editing tool to create your heart, you have no control over where it decides to start the path. The simplest solution would be to manually draw the path yourself.  Or if you learn how SVG path definitions work, you can rearrange the path in a text editor.

Comment: I'd rather not mess with the path manually in the text editor. Best solution I found so far is hacky: Break the closed path at a specific anchor/node. This forces the ends of the now open path to be located at the breakage. And then move the ends so close together again that there is no visible "gap". It's no longer a closed path, but it looks just like one.